# Unable to modify element with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to loop the students array and modify the html elements to print a card for each student.

However the code below fails at `page.evaluate` and gives the following error:

```
Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: student is not defined
```

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`file://${__dirname}/card/card.html`);

  console.log(students);

  for (const student of students) {
    console.log(student.name);
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = student.name;
      document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = student.id;
      document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = student.text;
    });

    await page.screenshot({ path: `example-${student.id}.png` });
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: the console.log(students) works inside the self calling function but does work in page.evaluate. Why is that?

Comment: You pass a function as a parameter into "await page.evaluate()". That function probably doesn't know about any variables outside of itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page.evaluate()` parameter is executed in the browser context, so you need to transfer any variables from Node.js context explicitly as additional arguments and parameters:

```js
await page.evaluate((student) => {
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = student.name;
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = student.id;
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = student.text;
}, student};
```

Comment: thank you. I think I understood. I'm familiarizing myself with nodejs as I go. page.evaluate() recieves student as an argument and it passes it on to the callback function I provide it with. I did try passing student to the argument of the callback function, but I did not pass it to page.evaluate() so that is why it must have not worked.

Comment: It is more complicated here than usual in JS: `puppeteer` transfers all `page.evaluate()` aruments as serialized data from Node.js context to browser context where the function argument is recreated from string and called with other arguments so it can access the data from Node.js context.